# How to erase sensitive information from Subversion?

Tags: svn

I one of the previous versions of my code, stored in a Subversion repository, there is sensitive information. How to erase it while keeping all other versions?

**EDIT**: The repository is Google Code Project Hosting, so I can't dump and restore the repository =(

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do by yourself.  Can you ask Google to destroy the repository, and then rebuild it?

Comment: Perhaps I can do it, if I choose a new name for the project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Want you want is a SVN feature commonly called "obliterate", which unfortunately still is not implemented.

As a workaround, you will have to dump, filter & reimport your repository. See e.g. the entry in the SVN faq [How do I completely remove a file from the repository's history?](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#removal).

BTW: It's a dupe :-).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663584/subversion-permanently-remove-incorrectly-checked-in-directory-project

**EDIT:**

> The repository is Google Code Project Hosting, so I can't dump and
>   restore the repository =(

As far as I can see, the only solution in this case is to (ask Google to) reset your respository (see [this FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ#How_can_I_reset_the_repository?), and this [blog post](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2008/03/best-practices-repository-resets.html)). This will completely remove all data from the repository (both current data and history), as if you had just started the repository using `svnadmin create`.

Obviously, you'll need a backup of your repository first.

The best solution probably is:

- create a backup of your repo using `snvsync` (this will also back up the history)
- do the dump/filter/restore dance (see above) on your backup of the repo, to remove the problematic commmits
- reset the Google repository
- put back your filtered repo, again using `snvsync` (see FAQ [How do I import my existing source code?](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ#How_do_I_import_my_existing_source_code?) )

Answer (score 7):

You can't remove what's commited to subversion other than completely dump, erase the original, and recreate the repository from the dump.

If you want to completely remove a file/path, you can do that with the svndumpfilter:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repository > svndump
svndumpfilter exclude path/to/sensitivefile > svndump-excluded
svnadmin create /tmp/newrepository
svnadmin load /tmp/newrepository < svndump-excluded
```

Then backup your  /path/to/repository  and replace it with /tmp/newrepository after you've verified everything is ok.

If you want to only exclude a single revision, you'd have to do something like

```
svnadmin dump  -r 0:1000 /path/to/repository > svndump1
svnadmin dump  -r 1002:HEAD --incremental /path/to/repository > svndump2
svnadmin create /tmp/newrepository
svnadmin load /tmp/newrepository <svndump1
svnadmin load /tmp/newrepository <svndump2
```

That is, revision 1001 is excluded. You can't do it more fine grained btw, a whole revision have to be excluded. Same deal here, backup your original repository, verify that everything needed in the new repository is there.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of work, but fortunately there are good explanations around, [such as this one by Rob Gonda](http://www.robgonda.com/blog/index.cfm/2005/7/10/SVN-Obliterate).