# With SVN, is it possible to prevent someone from updating to a specific revision?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

One of my coworkers accidentally committed personal information to our repository. I have reverted the change so that no one will get the file from future updates, but I was hoping to take it a step further and prevent someone from intentionally going back to the revision to look at the personal information.

I have seen that there is no way to simply delete the revision, but is there maybe a way to lock it out so that no one can update to that revision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294568/how-to-erase-sensitive-information-from-subversion) but as far as I know, there is no easy way to achieve this in svn. I know you can delete commits from a git repo history, so if that is an option I would recommend migrating to git in future projects to avoid this kind of  problems.

Comment: I work for a large company that is in the process of migrating from SVN to git. The other repository I've been working with was migrated, but this one hasn't been done yet.