# Is there any way of deleting revisions for a particular file using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have a file in an svn repo committed that has some sensitive data

I dont want to revert any changes , I want to not show any revisions when a user goes to look at the Show Log in the repository.

How can I do this using TortoiseSVN? Does an option exist in the TortoiseSVN menu, or do I need to use the command line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to erase sensitive information from Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294568/how-to-erase-sensitive-information-from-subversion)

Comment: not really this does the entre repo, all i want to do it is for a single repo file.