# Removing revisions on google code?

Tags: google-code

How can I completely remove a revision from the SVN on google code's project hosting website? I would like to delete the revision from the website so nobody can view or access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless things have changed since [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303247/how-do-i-prune-old-revisions-in-subversion/303256#303256) was posted, it doesn't seem like it's really possible to do in SVN other than creating a new repository.

As far as Google Code goes, I don't believe they would let you remove anything, since afaik once something is open source, it cannot be made closed source (future versions can, but anything released remains open source).

Answer (score 0):

Do a [rollback](http://www.rustyrazorblade.com/2007/04/how-to-roll-back-commits-to-an-earlier-version-of-a-repository-in-svn/) of the change.