# Can I prune old revisions in SVN?

Tags: svn

As the title, just wondering if this is available now? I'm using TortoiseSVN and I didn't see this option.

There's a post in 2008 which says SVN official team has planned to implement this functionality

[How do I prune old revisions in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303247/how-do-i-prune-old-revisions-in-subversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot prune (official term is "obliterate") revisions or files.

There was a working(?) prototype, but not working well enough for release in 1.7 the feature was dropped for more pressing issues.

[See here for the bugtracker entry](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=516)